# Debugging nodejs in server

Tags: node.js, web-services

I'm using Plesk virtual server to host my Nodejs server. Plesk is managing the node js and starting it automatically and I don't have an option to start it from terminal, and because of that, I find it really hard to debug my application. On the localhost it's running perfectly but on the server there are some errors. 
On the localhost I used console.log to output information, but now I don't have anything to receive this output...

I'm pretty new to nodejs and don't know all the tools I can use for debug... Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392900/is-it-possible-to-debug-a-currently-running-production-node-application